# Analytic exponential function problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Let $x>0.$ How do i show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp{(-xn^2z)}$ defines an analytic function on $\Re(z)>0?$

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,a)$, see [Jacobi elliptic $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\left\langle \exp(-xn^2 z)\right\rangle_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a sequence of analytic functions on the half plane $\Omega := \{z : \Re(z) > 0\}$ (in fact, they are entire), it suffices to show that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \exp(-xn^2z)$ converges uniformly on every closed disk in $\Omega$. Let $D$ be any closed disk in $\Omega$, and let $t$ be the distance from $D$ to the imaginary axis. If $z\in D$, $\Re(z) \ge t$, so that $$|\exp(-xn^2 z)| = e^{-xn^2\Re(z)} \le e^{-xn^2t}.$$ Since $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty e^{-xn^2t} < \infty$, by the Weierstrass M-test, the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \exp(-xn^2 z)$ converges uniformly on $D$.

Comment: Pls., what is the justification that $\left\langle \exp(-xn^2 z)\right\rangle_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a sequence of analytic functions on the half plane $\{z : \Re(z) > 0\}?$

Comment: Those functions are complex-differentiable on $\Omega$. In fact, they are complex-differentiable at every point of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Pls., Could you shade more light on using the M-test in concluding that the series converges uniformly on D?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: In applying the M-test

Comment: @AyshaA. if $f_n(z) = \exp(-xn^2z)$, then $|f_n| \le M_n$ on $D$, where $M_n := e^{-xn^2t}$. Since $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty M_n < \infty$, the Weierstrass $M$-test ensures that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly on $D$.